# Selecting a cell in a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I'm not expert at excel but I am trying to have 2 inputs one for a row and one for a column but I'm trying to have it select in a range base off what was entered ex.

```
BA = 0.31
GF = 32
```

so the table is something like this

```
|__________|______GF_____________|
|BA        | > 90 |61-90 | 30-60 |
|0.25-0.29 | 80 g | 60 g | 40 g  | 
|0.3-0.34  | 80 g | 60 g | 10 g  |
|0.35-0.39 | 20 g | 20 g | 10 g  |
```

I tried the following but that didn't work:
`=INDEX(C4:J11,MATCH(B15,A4:B11,1),MATCH(B14,C3:J3,1))`

Comment: By selecting do you mean referencing?

Comment: yes reference, I want to input a BA and a GF and it will produce one of the values below based on what was entered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=INDEX($G$2:$I$4,MATCH(B2,$F$2:$F$4,1),MATCH(C2,$G$1:$I$1,1))`

I used absolute references so the lookup doesn't drift away from the data.

[image: Example Excel Spreadsheet]

I found a site that helped explain the approximate match using grades as an example.
[index-match-approximate](https://exceljet.net/formula/basic-index-match-approximate)

Comment: I actually ended up figuring it out if I ended up using 0.25
0.3
0.35
0.4
0.45
0.5
0.55
0.6 instead of adding in the columB for the end of the range it works for me! thank you guys!